# Is it possible to use the Any trait through channels?

Tags: rust

This example is not right but it gives an idea of what I expect:

```
fn main() {
    let (chan, port) = channel();

    load(chan);

    let r = port.recv().unwrap().unwrap();
    println!("{}", r.downcast_ref::<String>().unwrap());
}

pub fn load<T:Send + Any>(sender: Sender<Option<T>>) {
    // do some works

    sender.send(Some(String::new("test") as Any);
}
```

I can't go further than this, due to these kinds of errors:

```
error: non-scalar cast:
error: cast to unsized type:
```

I am not sure, but Servo has something similar using the `Deserialize`/`Serialize` traits from Serde.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE]. You should be able to provide, in the question, example code that produces the errors you are receiving. Without that, we can't understand what your problem is. Right now, your sample code isn't even *syntactically valid*, but I'm sure you don't want answers on how to properly close your parenthesis! ^_^ Attempting to compile it in one of the [playgrounds](https://play.integer32.com/) should help you create a MCVE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send a *boxed trait object* of the `Any` trait through a channel:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let (chan, port) = channel();

    load(chan);

    let r = port.recv().expect("Unable to receive");
    println!("{}", r.downcast_ref::<String>().expect("Not a string"));
}

pub fn load(sender: Sender<Box<Any>>) {
    let s = String::from("test");
    let s = Box::new(s) as Box<Any>;
    sender.send(s).expect("Unable to send");
}
```

---

Your original attempt doesn't make sense:

```
pub fn load<T:Send + Any>(sender: Sender<Option<T>>)
```

A generic type is determined at compile time, which means that `T` is a fixed type, such as `String`. If you know the type that is going through the channel, you don't need to use `Any`

```
String::new("test") as Any
```

This doesn't make sense because `String::new` takes no arguments. Additionally, you cannot cast a value to a trait - traits have no known size. They always need to be behind a pointer of some kind.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your tips and help ;). I would have loved to provide a Minimal/Complete/Verifiable example but my "example" was pure sci-fi in my head.